# How to use vue-datetime-picker in single file component

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, vue.js

I am trying to use vue-datetime-picker

```
<vue-datetime-picker class="vue-picker4" name="picker4"
                             :model.sync="result4"
                             type="time"
                             language="en-IN"
                             time-format="LT">
</vue-datetime-picker>

import VueDatetimePicker from "vue-datetime-picker";

components: {
        "vue-datetime-picker": VueDatetimePicker
}
```

But still i am getting error

```
vue.js?3de6:525 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. 
(found in component <vue-datetime-picker>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately vue-datetime-picker does not working with vue.js 2

Answer (score -1):

instead of using `import`, try `require`

```
var VueDatetimePicker = require("vue-datetime-picker");

components: {
   "vue-datetime-picker": VueDatetimePicker
}
```

Comment: Same error, vue.js?3de6:525 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. 
(found in component <vue-datetime-picker>)

Comment: https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-datetime-picker this is what I am trying to use with Laravel single file component

Comment: @JagadeshaNH Are you using these in same file or different?

Comment: same file... I have a file called Stats.vue and inside that I am trying to use this component

Comment: Does it because your Vue.js version is different with `vue-datetime-picker`?